# How to join/merge on unequal pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join

I would like to convert the following sql statement to the equivalent pandas expression.

```
select 
  a1.country,
  a1.platform,
  a1.url_page as a1_url_page,
  a2.url_page as a2_url_page,
  a1.userid, a1.a1_min_time,
  min(a2.dvce_created_tstamp) as a2_min_time 
from( 
    select country, platform, url_page, userid,
      min(dvce_created_tstamp) as a1_min_time
    from pageviews 
    group by 1,2,3,4) as a1 
left outer join pageviews as a2 on a1.userid=a2.userid 
    and a1.a1_min_time < a2.dvce_created_tstamp
    and a2.url_page <> a1.url_page
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I am aware of the merging command of pandas however in our case we have a composite join clause that includes also **inequality**. I haven't found some documentation on how to handle this case.

Of course I can think as a last resort to iterate through dataframes but I do not think that this is the most efficient way to do it.

For example we can add some sample input data

`----------------------------------------------------------------
| country | platform | url_page | userid | dvce_created_tstamp |
|----------------------------------------------------------------
|   gr    |   win    |    a     |  bar   | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |
|   gr    |   win    |    b     |  bar   | 2019-01-01 00:01:00 |
|   gr    |   win    |    a     |  bar   | 2019-01-01 00:02:00 |
|   gr    |   win    |    a     |  foo   | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |
|   gr    |   win    |    a     |  foo   | 2019-01-01 01:00:00 |`

The response from sql 
 [image: Expected SQL Response]

When I use dataframe left merge command I get following output
[image: pandas left merge]

(edit: Add sample data)
It is obvious that we miss the rows with **null** a2_url_page

Comment: can you please provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: You can do the 'equality' join first then use .query or boolean indexing to filter the results down to what you want.